# How to write the xxd command in cmd in windows

Tags: windows

I am trying to use xxd command to convert string to hex. 
I have typed this command in cmd in windows xxd -p <<< "Hello world". 
But I have got this in my cmd 
'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I use xxd in cmd in windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Find some `xxd` and install it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: Write it in what? You can write a quick hex-converter in PowerShell in a few lines.

Comment: Not a programming question. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13182222/revisions which was migrated to SuperUser as https://superuser.com/questions/497953/convert-hex-dump-of-file-to-binary-program-file-on-windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use VIM for this

https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim73_46_s.zip

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74>.\xxd -v
```

Source: https://superuser.com/a/638850

Answer (score 10):

You could use git-bash to do that if you have installed it.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

These days the full linux kernel is made available and officially supported by windows via [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Once installed, a program like [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) can be used to execute linux commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you have powershell version 5.0 or later, you can use the powershell built-in function `Format-Hex`

```
$ Format-Hex '.\your-file-name'
```

It is not as powerfull as `xdd` but **you can run it natively in Windows**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you probably can't because it's a UNIX command...

What you can do is use GnuWin32/MinGW/CygWin, which are ports of Linux GNU utilities fro Windows.

Read more about them here:
[Difference between GNUWin32 and cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712550/difference-between-gnuwin32-and-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

See this utility clone.

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/xxd-for-windows/

The operation is similar. To see in hexadecimnal use "xxd file.txt", to see in binary use "xxd -b file.txt".

Answer (score 0):

I use xxd in the Windows subsystem for linux.  If you can, install Ubuntu or Kali Linux in windows by enabling wsl and then installing it via the Microsoft store.  you can run xxd and even use it nin combination with vi to hex edit files